# Base address of module loaded to the Linux Kernel

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I would like to know the base address at which a kernel module is loaded. What are the hex address `/proc/kallsyms` , `/sys/module/<MODULE_NAME>/sections/.init.text` and `/proc/modules` denotes. Which one I should use for debugging?

Comment: Physical or virtual? The information kernel provides about modules should be in the virtual address space in which kernel itself works.

Comment: @0andriy, My question is in the virtual address context.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel does the vmalloc and copies the contents of the modules passed from user space in the vmalloc'd buffer. The base address of module will be given by hex address pointed by /proc/modules

/proc/kallsyms: address where the symbol is loaded in memory

/sys/module/<MODULE_NAME>/sections/.init.text: start address of .init.text section in memory of that module

/proc/modules : The start address of module in memory

I would suggest to use kallsyms to debug as bp can be set in memory for that symbol